# How to implement device stored card(ios & android) to pay for application?

Tags: android, ios, node.js, payment

The mobile application I am building has got payment features (both for buying some coins and subscription of (1 month, 3 months and 12 months) for premium accounts. Here, I should not directly ask card details to pay for the users, instead I need to the user's device stored payment to pay for the mobile application (it may depend on ios and android) I am building. Also, how do the subscription works and keeps making charges to the mobile application timely?

Actually, I need help with the implementation mechanism. I am new to this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS payment you should go with in-app purchase. It is apple's payment gateway. It has facility to create different subscription plan with duration. So, all things which you want that managed by apple. Same way for android , google have also same mechanism for payment(in-app feature).

Comment: Mirant can you elaborate it please?

Comment: Kindly follow this link so you can get brief idea :-

1. https://www.appcoda.com/in-app-purchase-tutorial/
2. https://www.raywenderlich.com/5456-in-app-purchase-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Mirant thank you. I will try all these and come back if any problem comes by